# Copying pages from one EXCEL spreadsheet to another and including new page in formula in receiving spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a formula in the front page of spreadsheet 1 that totals values from 20 other pages in the spreadsheet (so the formula just adds a cell from page 2 plus a cell from page 3, etc. eg. =sum('SMITH'!N3+'JONES'!N3, etc.)

On a fairly regular basis I will need to move pages from another spreadsheet to spreadsheet 1.

I know how to do this... but the formula in spreadsheet 1 does not then include this new page. Is there a way to get the formula in spreadsheet 1 to automatically include the new page that's been added?

NB. I'm using Microsof Office Professional Plus 2016

Comment: What do you mean by Page , is that Worksheet or literally the Page after Page break ?

Answer (score 1):

Excel allows you to do this with 'Move or Copy...'.

Consider this:

- I have an Excel Spreadsheet called MyBook1.xlsx with 4 Sheets (pages) labelled Sheet1 to Sheet4
- Sheets2 to Sheet4 have some numeric value in cell A1
- If I enter the formula =SUM(Sheet2:Sheet3!A1) into A1 of Sheet1, it adds all the numbers as expected.

Now if I have another Excel Shreadsheet called MyBook2.xls that has one sheet called say 'Bob' and it has a numeric value in cell A1 say 100 that I want to move to the original Spreadsheet and I want Bob!A1 to be included in the sum formula, I can do the following:

- Open both spreadsheets (MyBook1.xlsx and MyBook2.xlsx)
- Go to MyBook2.xlsx and Right click on the tab labelled 'Bob'
- Select 'Move or Copy...' from the pop-up list
- Click the down arrow below 'To book:' label and this should show MyBook1.xlsx
- Select MyBook1.xlsx
- Select 'Sheet3' in the 'Before sheet:' list
- Click 'OK'

The spreadsheet MyBook1.xlsx now will include the new page before 'Sheet3' and the sum in Sheet1 will include the value from Bob!A1.

The key is that the cells to add are in the same position on each sheet and the new sheet is **moved anywhere between the sheets in the sum formula**. If you move the sheet before Sheet2 or after Sheet4, then it will not be included in the formula.